# Bot returning error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'" in MS Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer

I created a bot in BF Composer. It relies mostly on a series of adaptive Hero Cards. In Emulator and in Azure Web Chat the bot works fine but once I uploaded it to MS Teams (using App Studio) it returned error:
`Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'`

Initial hero card loads fine and the problem occurs once user chooses an option from the initial hero card (it should be followed by another hero card).

In Azure portal in Teams Channel I'm getting the following error:

```
March 17, 2022, 9:04 AM GMT+1
Invalid image URI
```

but I don't see how it relates and how it's problem only on Teams.

I'm using also App Insights but haven't seen anything useful there.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any Image URL in your Hero Cards?
Could you please check, if those URL's are in correct format?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Image URL's that I'm using are coming from the same source as the ones used in the initial Adaptive Card which displays fine. They're the exact same URLs - the same icons displayed - since the bot is in testing phase

Comment: @KRASSUSS - Could you please share the payload of hero card and repro steps to try at our end.

Comment: @KRASSUSS - Could you please confirm is your issue resolved or still facing the issue?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT
Hi!
The issue is still very much present, I'm working now on debugging the bot using VS but I'm facing issues there as well, I will get back to you once I have more data.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT is that normal that the bot created in Composer doesn't work when I'm debugging it VS? In other words can I just take the solution that Composer made and it should work in VS straight away or do I have to change something?

Comment: Bc for some reason the bot compiles and runs fine when launched from Composer app but in VS when I debug the solution I'm getting immiediate looped errors, the conversation doesn't even start

Comment: @KRASSUSS - Could you please share error logs?

Comment: @KRASSUSS - Could you please share the document which you are referring for this. Also share the code which you are trying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out when specifying parameters for the Adaptive Card one cannot leave parameter `IconUrl()` empty if one wants to publish it in Teams!